# Form with post request assigns request parameter to object bound to form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm working with Thymeleaf and Spring and I had something unexpected happen.

I have this Contact class:

```java
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CONTACT_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CONTACT_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "CONTACT_ID_GEN")
    private long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ContactInfo> info;

    //Constructors getter setters etc.
}
```

With a nested list of this Contact Info class:

```java
@Entity
public class ContactInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CONTACT_INFO_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CONTACT_INFO_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "CONTACT_INFO_ID_GEN")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "INFO_VALUE")
    private String infoValue;
    private InfoType infoType;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CONTACT_ID")
    private Contact contact;

    //Constructors getter setters etc.
}
```

My challenge was to make a form that would add a new Contact Info object, but it all has to go through Contact.

Using Thymeleaf and Spring, this is the form declaration I came up with

```html
<form th:action="'/add-new-contact-info/' + ${contact.id}" method="post" th:object="${newContactInfo}">
```

Here, newContactInfo is an empty object of type contactInfo and contact.id is the id of the parent Contact Object.

The idea is that if I want to add a contactInfo object for Cpntact with id 1, it would go to /add-new-contact-info/1

Now my form only had inputs for infoValue and infoType. There was no input field for id.

I expected the ID to be 0 as a default value and then once I call the save method of my repository, it would use the sequence to generate a new one.

But instead, Thymeleaf always gave the id the value that's in the path. So for /add-new-contact-info/{id}, the id of the received ContactInfo object would be {id}.

I've worked with Spring before but not Thyemleaf and I've never seen anything work like that. Usually the value of the bodyResponse object would be consisting only of values in the form, the values in the path should be separate no?

I found a fix where I just manually set the id to 0 immediately in my code and it works fine. Someone else who did the same thing as me simply changed the name of id to contactInfoId and that also worked.

Here is the method where I fixed it by setting the id to 0 in my controller with the "contactInfo.setId(0);" line:

```
@PostMapping("/add-new-contact-info/{id}")
public String makeNewContactInfo(ContactInfo contactInfo, @PathVariable long id, Model model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    contactInfo.setId(0);
    Optional<Contact> optRes = contactService.readById(id);
    if (optRes.isPresent()) {
        Contact contact = optRes.get();
        contact.getInfo().clear();
        contact.getInfo().add(contactInfo);
        return this.updateContact(contact);
    }
    String message = "Contact doesn't exist";
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Can anyone clarify for me why it works this way? And can it be avoided in a different way?

Comment: AFAIK, Thymeleaf is only involved in rendering the HTML, it is not involved in processing the POST call from the form to your Spring app. Please provide a [mre], which includes your controller.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the edits and reply! I'm not sure how much I should provide for a minimal reproducible example of a spring project. Would a github repo link to the minimum I had to build to reproduce the issue suffice? If so, here it is: https://github.com/ClementCadieux/stackOverflowMRC. Otherwise, I'd be happy to provide more.

Comment: Questions need to be self-contained, which means relevant code must be in the question itself, but I think your current update should be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to separate the entity from the form data object.

So create a `AddContactInfoFormData` object that represents the fields you have in your Thymeleaf form.

In your POST mapping, you would do something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/add-new-contact-info/{id}")
public String makeNewContactInfo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("formData") AddContactInfoFormData formData, BindingResult bindingResult, @PathVariable long id, Model model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "contacts/edit" // This should be the name of your Thymeleaf template so it is re-rendered with the errors
  }


    Optional<Contact> optRes = contactService.readById(id);
    if (optRes.isPresent()) {
        Contact contact = optRes.get();
        contact.replaceInfo(formData.toContactInfo());      
        return this.updateContact(contact);
    }
    String message = "Contact doesn't exist";
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

`AddContactInfoFormData` would have a `toContactInfo()` method that creates a new instance of `ContactInfo` based on the form data info received.

See [Form Handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for more info.

Comment: So essentially making a Data Transfer object for ContactInfo that wouldn't have an ID?